# SSIS Catalog Package error - Version of FlatFile destination not compatible with version of DataFlow

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssms, etl

Getting error

```
"The version of flat file destination is not compatible with this version of the dataflow"
```

when trying to execute a SSIS package from the catalog, the package executes well from visual studio. I have tried in catalog to run it both in 32 bit mode and in 64 bit.

the package just executes a stored procedure and exports the result as csv. I don't know what could be happening with it that is giving this "version not compatible"
searching for it I found something [similar](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/0cff32ea-3e9e-43b3-be7f-73c6b26a8029/ssis-package-just-failsnot-compatible-with-this-version-of-the-dataflow?forum=sqlintegrationservices)  and the recommendation was to delete a section with "version" in it, I did that and I get the same result.

These are the error I'm getting:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ Message Type ║ Action       ║ Message             ║ Message                                                                         ║ Message       ║ Subcomponent                    ║ Execution Path            ║
║              ║              ║   Time              ║                                                                                 ║   Source Name ║   Name                          ║                           ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ OnError      ║ View Context ║ 4-7-2020 5:05:23 PM ║ Export to Excel:Error: There were errors during                                 ║ Export        ║                                 ║ \Package1\Export to Excel ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   task validation.                                                              ║   to Excel    ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║                                                                                 ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ OnError      ║ View Context ║ 4-7-2020 5:05:23 PM ║ Export to Excel:Error: One or more component                                    ║ Export        ║ SSIS.Pipeline                   ║ \Package1\Export to Excel ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   failed validation.                                                            ║   to Excel    ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║                                                                                 ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ OnError      ║ View Context ║ 4-7-2020 5:05:23 PM ║ Export to Excel:Error: Flat File Destination                                    ║ Export        ║ SSIS.Pipeline                   ║ \Package1\Export to Excel ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.                         ║   to Excel    ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║                                                                                 ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ OnError      ║ View Context ║ 4-7-2020 5:05:23 PM ║ Export to Excel:Error: The component is                                         ║ Export        ║ Flat File Destination [2]       ║ \Package1\Export to Excel ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The ║   to Excel    ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   contact information for this component is "Flat File                          ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   Destination;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft        ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   Corporation; All Rights Reserved;                                             ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;1".                                      ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║                                                                                 ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ OnError      ║ View Context ║ 4-7-2020 5:05:23 PM ║ Export to Excel:Error: The version of Flat File                                 ║ Export        ║ SSIS.Pipeline                   ║ \Package1\Export to Excel ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   Destination, clsid {0667D728-1E5F-4BB6-863D-B29D3F405706} is not compatible   ║   to Excel    ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   with this version of the DataFlow.                                            ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║                                                                                 ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ OnError      ║ View Context ║ 4-7-2020 5:05:23 PM ║ Export to Excel:Error: The version of Flat File                                 ║ Export        ║ Export to Excel (SSIS.Pipeline) ║ \Package1\Export to Excel ║
║              ║              ║                     ║   Destination is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.              ║   to Excel    ║                                 ║                           ║
║              ║              ║                     ║                                                                                 ║               ║                                 ║                           ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

please let me know what other information I can add. I have other packages running in the server so SSIS catalog works. and this particular package works from visual studio, but not on the catalog. the component that is failing is a dataflow that has an OLEDB Connection to a flat file destination:

[image]

with a basic flat file connection manager:
[image]

Update:
I found tha tif I do the deploy from visual studio the package works when I execute in SSMS. the problem is that I need to import the package, since it's going to be installed in a third party server not connected with visual studio.
I'm trying to replicate this on my computer (server is in my computer) and it works with deploy from VS but not when importing.
this is the error that I get when executing the imported file (the table above also shows it):
[image]

Comment: It sounds like you are missing some optional features for SSIS.  Which version of SSIS is on your server?  Which version of SSDT are you using with VStudio?

Comment: Also, on your server, you must be using a different filename & path.  Could you check permissions. Maybe try granting Full to Everyone just for that folder.

Comment: the server is located on my computer, so paths are the same. I'm executing as administrator as well. I have SSIS 14.0 running. and other SSIS packages are running in the server (one for uploading from excel to db work, this from db to flat file doesn't) the error says it's flat file version related to dataflow

Comment: What version of VS are you authoring your SSIS packages in? What tool and version, did you use to deploy to SQL Server catalog? What version of SQL Server have you deployed to?

Comment: I'm using VS2019 building with target SQL Server 2017, I deployed using catalog and deploy from VS.  the version of SQL Server is 2017 - 14.0.2027.2

Comment: I have an update, adding it to main post, I found a way it works, but not the way I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was encountering a very similar issue whilst upgrading a Visual Studio 2017 package with a `TargetServerVersion` of SQL Server 2012 to Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2017.

Other than when we ran the package in the design location from within Visual Studio, we kept getting the error:

> The version of flat file destination is not compatible with this version of the dataflow

I resolved the issue by:

- Importing the original package into Visual Studio 2019 using the *Integration Services Import Project Wizard*
- Setting the `TargetServerVersion` to SQL Server 2017
- Converting Deployment Model; and
- Deploying to all *Servers/SSMS* locates required using the `ispac` file.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this by going to Project Property and change the TargetServerVersion from SQL Server 2019 to 2017
[image]

Comment: I had the same error.  I was using SSIS with VS 2017 with a SQL Server 2019 database, and I was trying to run the package via the version of DTExec.exe installed with SQL Server 2017.  So which TargetServerVersion to use - SQL 2019 for the database, or SQL 2017 for the DTExec tool?  In the end setting TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2017 worked.  I figure that was needed to work with the DTExec tool, and that the SQL Server Native Client used by the database connection manager insulated the package from the version of SQL Server it was connecting to.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, because the project was targeted to SQL 2019, while I am using SQL 2017. I changed it to SQL 2017 in the VS project properties and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, because the project was targeted to SQL 2019. After sitting down with the engineer, we changed it to 2016.

[you are going to go to the solution explorer and right click on the project name and click on properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyAM3.png)

[then click on general and for target serverversion click the year that your server is at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJaG6.png)

1.Go to solution Explorer
2.Right Click on your project name (this is bolded)
3. Click Properties
4. Click Configuration Properties
5.Click General
6.For target server version click SQK Server 2016 or whatever server version you have
7. Click ok

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I used "SQL server Agent" to run the SSIS package

" Description: The version of Flat File Department is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  End Error  Error: 2023-12-04 10:26:46.04     Code: 0xC0048020"

I did this

[right click on your project and select properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVB4Q.png)

[Then I changed TargetServerVersion from SQL Server 2022 to SQL Server 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjpeE.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't this the same approach as VanilaNitroPepsi proposed here?